# Drawing multiple lines from origin

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, line

I have following list of points (x,y sets):

```
pts = [ 
        [1, 3 ],
        [4, 8 ],
        [-2,4 ],
        [-3,-5],
        [4, 2 ]]
```

I have to draw lines from origin (0,0) to each of these points and I am using following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for pt in pts:
    plt.plot([0,pt[0]], [0,pt[1]])
plt.show()
```

It works all right but is there any way I can vectorize this code? Can I plot all lines using the list itself in one go without using `for` loop?

Comment: Not sure about lists but you could do it with numpy arrays if that is an option?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I prefer numpy arrays.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `numpy` arrays you can its indexing along with `numpy.zeros()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pts = [ [1, 3 ],
        [4, 8 ],
        [-2,4 ],
        [-3,-5],
        [4, 2 ]]

arr = np.array(pts)

plt.plot([np.zeros(5), arr[:,0]], [np.zeros(5), arr[:,1]])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. The two `plot` arguments are the horizontal and vertical components. The columns represent successive datapoints in a line/curve; the rows are independent lines/datasets in the plot.